# React - Calling setState in a function that's called from another class throws not a function exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to achieve here is, I want the value to be updated in the imported class B's state by calling the B's function **init()** from the class A. I'm initializing a **new** Object of B class and calling the init function through the object.

**Class A**

```
  import B from 'b.js'

  class A extends Component{
      componentDidMount(){
          const b=new B();
          b.init("hey");
        }
   }
```

In **Class B**: I'm updating the state using the init function, but it appears that I'm getting **setState is not a function** error. I have also tried binding init function in the constructor, but the error stays the same.

```
    class B extends Component{
      constructor(props){
       super(props);
       state = {
            text:""
         }
       }

       init=(text)=>{
          this.setState({text})
        }
     }
```

Comment: That code doesn't seem like it would have that problem. (But it's also almost certainly an anti-pattern; use a constructor in `B` and a prop for the text.) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Your calling `setState` on a unmounted component, that doesn't make any sense.  If you want to set the initial state, just do -> `Object.assign(this.state, {text})`

Comment: @Keith What if I want to update the state? The same method should work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `init`, that is what the `constructor` is for. You should pass in the text as a prop to component B when you create it:

```
import B from 'b.js';

class A extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const b = new B({ initialText: 'hey' });
    }
}
```

Then you can set the state inside the constructor for B.

```
state = {
    text: prop.initialText,
};
```

Be careful though, setting the state from a prop is generally a bad idea. See the note block here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor for more details.

Comment: I have multiple functions inside B, which I'm calling from class A. So I cannot send the values as props to that class. The params of each functions are different.

Comment: Then use a state on A and send them as params to the functions on B. If B isn't mounted, you can't use state on it. Make a service if you really want this design pattern

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is. Perhaps updating the question with what you currently have and what you are trying to accomplish would help.